# NLP data preparation and sorting for text-classification task

Tags: python, nlp, dataset, text-classification, spacy

I read a lot of tutorials on the web and topics on stackoverflow but one question is still foggy for me. If consider just the stage of collecting data for multi-label training, what way (see below) are better and whether are both of them acceptable and effective?

1. Try to find 'pure' one-labeled examples at any cost.
2. Every example can be multi labeled.

For instance, I have articles about war, politics, economics, culture. Usually, politics tied to economics, war connected to politics, economics issues may appear in culture articles etc. I can assign strictly one main theme for each example and drop uncertain works or assign 2, 3 topics.

I'm going to train data using Spacy, volume of data will be about 5-10 thousand examples per topic.

I'd be grateful for any explanation and/or a link to some relevant discussion.

Comment: What spacy model do you plan to use for this work?

Comment: @amirouche , I'm not sure. Probably, I'll start with the smallest and, If it need be, change to the biggest. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I asked the wrong question, which task model do you plan to use NER, POS or something else?

Comment: FWIW, I have been trying to tackle a more difficult task (hierarchical classification), in this project : https://github.com/amirouche/sensimark What I was said is to compare to topic modeling that rely on TF-IDF.

Comment: @amirouche It's a good question. I have to think about it.

Comment: @amirouche , thank you for your piece of work. I'm sure it will be useful for me. I'll carefully explore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try ***OneVsAll / OneVsRest*** strategy. This will allow you to do both: predict exact one category without the need to strictly assign one label.

> Also known as one-vs-all, this strategy consists in fitting one
>   classifier per class. For each classifier, the class is fitted against
>   all the other classes. In addition to its computational efficiency
>   (only n_classes classifiers are needed), one advantage of this
>   approach is its interpretability. Since each class is represented by
>   one and one classifier only, it is possible to gain knowledge about
>   the class by inspecting its corresponding classifier. This is the most
>   commonly used strategy for multiclass classification and is a fair
>   default choice.
>
> This strategy can also be used for multilabel learning, where a
>   classifier is used to predict multiple labels for instance, by fitting
>   on a 2-d matrix in which cell [i, j] is 1 if sample i has label j and
>   0 otherwise.

Link to docs:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html